# Ruby sort by two fields added together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I'm pulling in rows from a database using the following:

```
@items = @product.inventory_items.where("products.hidden = ?", false)
```

This contains three fields - `:regular_price`, `:sale_price`, and `:shipping_cost`. How can I sort the items by total price, so that the lowest combined price and shipping cost is first?

Comment: What total cost are you wanting to order by? The total cost could be `regular_price + shipping_cost` or `sale_price + shipping_cost` depending upon whether you want the regular price or the sale price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order by total sale price, then try:

```
@items = @product.inventory_items.select('*, (sale_price+shipping_cost) as total_sale_price').order('total_sale_price')
```

Similarly for total regular price. Or mix and match as you desire. You can add a `where` clause to the end as needed.

To take this a step further, as discussed in the comments, we can use the `regular_price` if the `sale_price` is null:

For MySQL:

```
@items = @product.inventory_items.select('*, (IFNULL(sale_price, regular_price) + shipping_cost) as total_price').order('total_price')
```

For Postgresql:

```
@items = @product.inventory_items.select('*, (COALESCE(sale_price, regular_price) + shipping_cost) as total_price').order('total_price')
```

Comment: This works great, but not all products have a sale_price. Is there any way to have some sort of conditional? If sale_price, total_sale_price = sale_price + shipping. Else total_sale_price = regular_price + shipping?

Comment: @Drew is the value `0` if it doesn't have that price, or is it `NULL`?

Comment: @Drew, I suppose if `regular_price` is always guaranteed to be non-zero, you could do something like this: `((full_price * FLOOR((full_price + 0.005)/(full_price-sale_price)) + sale_price + shipping_cost) as total_price`. The `0.005` tweak is to avoid getting a `0` if the ratio is `0.999..`.

Comment: I couldn't get your code to give me reliable results. The database behind this is PostreSQL. Working directly on the database, I was able to get this query to work: `SELECT *,(IFNULL(sale_price,regular_price) + shipping_cost) as total_price from products order by total_price`.  Any idea how to incorporate the IFNULL() function into ruby?

Comment: @Drew, yes that's good. I was fishing a little for the correct expression in SQL to achieve the desired result, not being certain that the `IFNULL` would work in that context. In Ruby, did you try making it part of your `select(...)` statement? If it works in SQL directly as your `SELECT` expression, it should work as `@product.inventory_items.select('*,(IFNULL(sale_price,regular_price) + shipping_cost) as total_price').order('total_price')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@product.inventory_items.
  select(:regular_price, :sale_price, :shipping_cost, 
         "(regular_price + sale_price) as sum_of_prices").
  order(sum_of_prices: :asc, shipping_cost: :asc)
```

Note: The `where("products.hidden = ?", false)` didn't make sense to me, so I removed it.